# SortFields.Clear is not turning off filter in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping for a bit of help here.  I have some VB code that is supposed to disable filters and it's not working.  I know the issue is with the way I have the macro written, but I cannot figure it out.

```
Sub Schedule_Update_Ops_Site_AweaLP2516()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Schedule_Update_Ops_Site_AweaLP2516.xlsx"
Windows("Schedule_Update_Ops_Site_AweaLP2516.xlsx").Activate
Range("A2:Q5000").EntireRow.Delete
Windows("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm").Activate
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xC

Sheets("Awea-LP2516").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Range("A1:Q1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Q").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="x"
 Columns("A:Q").Select
    Selection.Copy

Windows("Schedule_Update_Ops_Site_AweaLP2516.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A2:Q2").Delete
       
With ActiveSheet.Sort

.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1"), Order:=xlAscending
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F1"), Order:=xlAscending
.SetRange Range("A2:Q2000")
.Header = xlYes
.Apply
End With


Workbooks("Schedule_Update_Ops_Site_AweaLP2516.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Windows("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:Q").Select
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A2").Select

MsgBox ("The Awea-LP2516 schedule has been successfully updated on the Napoleon Machine IOS."), 
vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did to resolve was add the following code after I activated the Master sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```